# file_put_contents is adding backslashes to the code

Tags: php

I use `file_get_contents()` & `file_put_contents()` to load and save a `.css` file.  After saving the loaded file the `file_put_contents()` function will escape the quotes, how can this be prevented.

```
$file = 'pathto/base.css';

$ta = $file_get_contents($file);// load

<textarea name="editor"><?php echo $ta;?></textarea>

// press submit button here

file_put_contents($file, $_POST['editor']);// save

// new css code will be something like this

.row:after{
    content:/"/";// not what we need

 }
```

Comment: `file_put_contents` just writes what you have to a file, it does no processing.  What does `var_dump($_POST['editor'])` show you?  How are you posting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stripslashes](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) is probably what you're looking for. Certain PHP installations will automagically escape strings for you by adding slashes. This should reverse that.

Check out [Magic Quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)

Answer (score 7):

Most likely you have [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

So just turn it off in `php.ini` and restart PHP.

---

To strip the slashes:

```
file_put_contents($file, stripslashes($_POST['editor']));
```

Comment: Yes this is turned on. I will use the stripslashes to fix this.